# Litespeed Cache Headers

Tags: caching, modx-revolution, litespeed, openlitespeed

We have just migrated from Apache to Litespeed and we are seeing a huge speed improvement of our websites already but we want to migrate to also having Litespeed cache. The problem is I've edited our WHM settings as below, but I'm always getting the header response of no-cache as shown below. What am I missing?

CacheRoot /tmp/ramdisk
CacheLookup on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=cache-control:max-age=120]

<FilesMatch ".(css|ico|flv|gif|jpeg|jpg|js|pdf|png|swf|text|html|text/html)$">
Header append Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
Header edit Cache-Control "^[, ]*$" "max-age=1800, public"

**Website Header Response**

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*
Cache-Control:
no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding:
br
Content-Length:
27281
Content-Type:
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:
Wed, 21 Feb 2024 21:17:21 GMT
Expires:
Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:
no-cache
Server:
LiteSpeed

Vary:
Accept-Encoding,User-Agent,User-Agent
X-Xfpc-Cache:
Hit

Answer (score 0):

This issue has already been posted on the LiteSpeed Support Forum where this issue is being addressed, but the reporter is no longer responding.